# Coordinates and basis vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: vector-spaces

Do coordinates and the basis vectors always come together when representing a vector in a vector space (For example $\mathbb{R}^n$)? In other words, can I talk about coordinates without basis vectors or vice-versa?

Comment: Yea coordinates imply a choice of basis vectors, and the coefficients of basis vectors are your coordinates. I would guess its more natural to think of coordinates as an abbreviation for writing out the basis vectors

Comment: When we first learn about $\Bbb R^n$ we talk about coordinates without talking about basis vectors; in that preliminary context, the standard basis $(1,0,\dots,0)$, $(0,1,0,\dots,0)$, ..., $(0,\dots,0,1,0)$, $(0,\dots,0,1)$ underlies the coordinate system without us taking notice of it. Later, in linear algebra, we realize that coordinates and bases go hand in hand as jcneek says.

Comment: My confusion arises from the fact that the canonical basis seems to be special in some sense because every other basis is kind of build on top of the canonical basis. Moreover when talking about different systems of coordinates it also seems that the different coordinates only make sense when view on top of the canonical or cartesian coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

1. let's take a simple example that you can represent in a plane : $\{u,v\}$ with $u=(2,0)$ and $v=(0,1)$, is a basis of $\mathbb R ^2$. $\forall (x,y)\in \mathbb R^2, $ exists a unique $(\xi,\eta)\in\mathbb R \times\mathbb R : (x,y)=\xi(2,0)+\eta(0,1)$.
   We call them the coordinates of $(x,y)$ in the basis $\{u,v\}$[so we need a vector $(x,y)$ to define them.]
   For example, $2$
   and $5$ are the coordinates of (4,5) in $\{u,v\}$.

2. Now, if your vector space is the real vector space $\mathcal{F}(\mathbb R,\mathbb R)$ [you can add functions and multiply functions by a real number and all axioms of vector spaces hold], there are no a priori coordinates, even if you can talk about the exponential function as a vector for example.

Comment: I think I understand that, what troubles me is the fact that we always talk about different basis with respect to the canonical basis.

Comment: What Greg Martin says about the canonical basis and learnings is interesting, isn't it? You would need a specific exercise for you to be able to clarify your difficulties on the exercise in question, for example a simple geometry exercise where you would have to make a change of bases.

Comment: Since you talked about change of bases, a change in the system of coordinates is equivalent to a change of the basis vectors?

Comment: maybe it can help : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4562090/if-t-is-the-linear-transformation-whose-matrix-is-a/4562128#4562128