# If $T$ is the linear transformation whose matrix is $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I am a beginner in linear algebra and I have a doubt in the following part of matrix representation

If $T$ is the linear transformation whose matrix is $A$ wrt to the standard basis then if we take any vector $v$ then the image of $v$ is $A(v)$.

Assume that for the same linear transformation we have a matrix $A'$ which is not with respect to standard basis but it is with respect to any other basis then the image of $v$ should be $A'(v)$ or we need to find the coordinate matrix wrt to the new basis say $v'^T$ then $T(v)=A'(v'^T)$ is the image.

I think it would be the second one but I don't have a conclusive proof for it.

Comment: $A'$ only "understands" vectors when written in terms of the corresponding basis. If you calculate $Av$, you won't get the coordinate vector of $T(v)$, you will get the coordinate vector of $T(x)$, where $x$ is the vector whose coordinate vector is $T$.

Comment: you should take an example: I'm not a beginner in linear algebra but without the support of an example, I have trouble understanding what you write( in $\mathbb R ^2, \{i,j\}$ the canonical basis and say $\{b_1=j,b_2=i\}$ the other basis , and $T:(x,y)\to (x,-y)$

Answer (score 1):

To understand what is happening, let's see an example (I advise to make a drawing)
In $\mathbb R ^2, \{i,j\}$ the canonical basis and $\{b_1=j,b_2=i\}$ the other basis, and $T:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R ^2, (x,y)\to (x,-y)$((you can propose a geometric interpretation of $T$.)

With your notations, $A=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\0 & -1\end{bmatrix}$ and $A'=\begin{bmatrix}-1 & 0 \\0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$.

For example, let's see the effect of $T$ on the point $(4,2)$: using $A$, we get $4i-2j$; using $A'$, we get $-2b_1+4b_2=-2j+4i$ (well, it's the same thing.)